# Material UI with NextJS13 app router. Client and Server components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, next.js13

I wanted to make a server component with MUI's BOX/Container, but I get an error "Error: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it. Read more: [https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/context-in-server-component"](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/context-in-server-component%22). Does it mean that MUI is not yet optimized for NextJS's app router version?